SQS FIFO messageSent not matching messageReceived on Lambda Trigger
I has some weird SQS FIFO + Lambda Trigger behaviour, and hope someone can guide me.

I have a SQS FIFO queue with these settings that's linked to a Lambda Trigger:


Each message's body is unique, so the content based deduplication will not filter any messages.

My Lambda is processing "batches on 1", as my use cases requires this strict "1 at a time" requirement. It has only 1 concurrency, 4min timeout and has the following trigger settings.



EventBridge Pipe is sending messages into the FIFO SQS, and due to the limitations of not being able to have unique messageGroupIds, each message has the SAME messageGroupId.

My lambda code, processes the messages and deletes them correctly after completing the execution.


Problem I've having:
I've noticed that on multiple occasions when my queue gets message via the Pipe (when the messages are sent consecutively with a few seconds between each message), on SQS the messageSent (items being pushed into SQS by the pipe) is correct, but the lambda is not triggered based on the messageSent numbers and therefore messageReceive count is not the same as messageSent. Worse part is that the messages are not available in the queue anymore (can't see them in Messages Available or Messages in Flight) and also not in DLQ as well. I've read that this is an issue with SQS queues with "low numbers" of events due to the distributed nature of AWS SQS?
What is the recommended fix to ensure that all messages in the SQS FIFO, will trigger the Lambda?
Thanks very much!
